# Is this the correct way to use an object with a function inside it?

Tags: javascript, function, object, instance

Is this the correct way to create an Object and place a function inside of it? Every example I come across uses code that is to simple to understand and to use effectively in an actual situation. So I'm trying to figure this out by doing.

```
function calc() //creating an empty object named calc
{
}

var calc = new calc(); //creating a new instance of the calc object

calc.arithmetic = function maths (input) 
{
    var str = input;
    var a=str.substr(1,1); 
    var b=str.substr(2,1);
    var c=str.substr(3,1);

    if(b == "+")
    {
        answerNumber = a + c;
    }
    else if(b == "-")
    {
        answerNumber = a + c;
    }
    else if(b == "*")
    {
        answerNumber = a * c;
    }
    else if(b == "/")
    {
        answerNumber = a / c;
    }
}
document.getElementById("input").value=answerNumber;




document.write(calc.arithmetic(input))  //calling the method in the context of the object.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting calc with a fresh object containing only myArithmetic here.

You should be doing `calc.myArithmetic=function(){};` instead - this adds a new property with your function as value, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Okay. I understand that part now. assuming the function even works, in theory would this call the function maths from within calc.arithmetic?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at Douglas Crockford site (http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html).

Comment: Okay, this seems to be setting me on the right track. thanks!